# vSphere Customization Specification and Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dhcp, vmware-vsphere, template

Has anyone noticed issues with #vSphere Customization Specification and #Ubuntu 17.10 (GNU/Linux 4.13.0-25-generic x86_64) – Now that the network settings are located in: `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`, I’m back to manually updating IP information (Server Naming still works).

Although the traditional `/etc/network/interfaces` reflects the information provided by the customization process, the host still acquires a DHCP issued address.  After some digging I was able to find out that this information was no longer being referenced and is now being pulled from:  `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

Here are the IP configuration details

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens160
#iface ens160 inet dhcp
iface ens160 inet static
address 10.200.255.6
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.200.255.0
broadcast 10.0.255.255
gateway 10.200.255.1
dns-nameservers 10.200.255.1
```

`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
ens160:
dhcp4: no
addresses: [10.200.255.6/24]
gateway4: 10.200.255.1
nameservers:
addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Shared via http://jermsmit.com/vsphere-customization-specification-and-ubuntu-17-10/

Comment: Not being an LTS release, you should expect limited support for it. I would expect VMware to have this sorted by the time 18.04 LTS is available.

Comment: Possibly, and I do hope so.  For now its been an inconvenience to me at best. Thanks for the response, it was inline with my thoughts on this also.